# Render array to markup after submitting a form

Tags: 7

In my Drupal 7 custom moudle, i would like to output result of form as an formatted array.
Simmilar like you can print_r or printf arrays.

```
 $form['results'] = array(
            '#type'     => 'item',
            '#markup'   => $form_state['temporary']
)
```

so  $form_state['temporary'] is array, but i do not want "array" text to show up but formatted array representation, whatewer is in it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try like:

```
'#markup' => '<pre>'.print_r($form_state['temporary'], true).'</pre>';
```

you could just save the `print_r()` value to variable and then output that to a Div or something ...

Comment: Ah... of course, as simple as that, i an an blind fool... tnx :)

Comment: @tenken, I am stuck on the part where you mention about "output that to a Div" , in my for submit I have set the results array but it does not print anywhere?